# Webkit bug with padding, box-sizing and jQuery's outerWidth() setter at some zoom levels

Tags: jquery, webkit

I am currently trying to fix some strange behaviour with zoom levels on dynamical width divs and I am a bit puzzled.

The problem happens when I try to set the same `outerWidth()` value, with jquery, on 2 divs with `box-sizing: border-box` one having a padding while the other does not and the browser zoom is set with "not round" values (e.g. 67% or 33% on chrome and almost every one on safari). The size is the same except at these levels where the one with the padding is smaller than the other one.

here is an example with my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/ARMMB/3/

Edit: To clarify the problem. There is a way to bypass this by wrapping it in an other div as @jimjimmy1995 said but it's not a perfect solution as it can't be used eveywhere without changing the whole design of the page. I'm more looking for a way to calculate the accurate size depending on the zoom level and paddings the way outerwidth should if it worked here.

the html:

```
<body>
    <div id ="a">text a</div>
    <div id ="b">text b</div>
</body>
```

the css:

```
#a{
    background-color: red;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    padding-left: 5px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#b{
    background-color: blue;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    newWidth= 150;
    $("#a").outerWidth(newWidth);
    $("#b").outerWidth(newWidth);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to wrap the text in another element and apply padding with that.

```
<div id ="a"><span id="pad">text a</span></div>
<div id ="b">text b</div>

#pad {
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XMwh4/)

Comment: That was the temporary solution I have been using on a part of my design, but I can't using it eveywhere due to a very complicated architecture. I was more looking for a way to calculate the accurate size depending on the zoom level and paddings the way outerwidth should if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Well basically the problem is that the browser sees the padding different on other zoom levels, if you inspect elements in safari you will see that although the padding is defined as 5px in the stylesheet the browser sees it as 4 px with zoom out. I made a function which basically thought will fix your problems but my best guess would be to use percentages for the padding and the detect the padding using `$(elem)[0].style.padding` and then detect the size in pixels for the rendered element by dividing the size by 100 would be the actual solution.
Anyway, here is the function I built http://jsfiddle.net/ARMMB/10/

Comment: It seems that the behaviour is pretty different in each browser. Your jsfiddle still does not work at 67% zoom level on Chrome at least, should it work? We understand that the zoom level implies differences. For example we've seen that the border sometimes change from 1px to 3px depending on the zoom. But in our case it seems that outerWidth() completely forgets the padding. What we are trying to do is find a reliable way to compute the whole outerWidth with border AND padding included. And understand if it is a jQuery bug too.

Comment: it isn't a jquery bug from what I've seen, jquery adds up just fine, the problem is with the way the browser renders sizes, making 5px actually become 4 px. My example only proves that problem and the solution I see is using percentages and if you can use that, starting from my example you can adapt the function to calculate the exact size of a certain percentage in pixels so that the size will look the same (proportionally) no mater the zoom level